# Regex: Delete all operators (commas) from tags < >

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have to delete all commas from tags (not from the entire html files):

```
<!DOCTYPE, html>
<html, xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ro">
<title>I, love, Myself, Now | Nick, Francisco</title>
<meta, property="fb:admins", content="1446157242"/>
<link, rel="sitemap" type="application/rss+xml" href="rss.xml" /> 
<meta, name="googlebot" content="index,follow"/>
<link, rel="shortcut, icon" href="goiu.ico"/>
<meta, http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,"/>
```

I made a regex, but is not too good.

FIND: `(?-s)(\G(?!^)|<,)((?!/>).)*?\K\s\s+`

REPLACE BY: `(leave empty)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<\w+|\G)(?:(?!>).)*?\K,`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
  <         # <
  \w+       # 1 or more word characters
 |         # OR
  \G        # restart from last match position
)           # end group
(?:         # non capture group
  (?!>)     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't ">" character after 
  .         # any character but newline
)*?         # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
,           # a comma
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @RobRob: You're welcome glad it helps.